# How can I run qwt examples using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm trying to run Qwt examples using VS2010. I've installed the Qt plugin for Visual Studio. I then open the .pro file of Qwt and the build succeeds. But I have no clue what to do next. Whenever I click run, it gives me a dialog which says

> unable to start programe E:\qwt-6.0.1\src..\lib\qwtd.dll

Does anyone have an idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to get the examples compiled using the command line tools. Key steps included:

1. Add the bin dir of qt and the lib dirs of qt and qwt to the path
2. Dont forget to run vcvars32.bat from Visual Studios bin directory
3. VC\bin should be in the path too
4. then follow the INSTALL instructions from qwt

After this I had a set of running examples in examples/bin of qwt. It's also easy to open one of them in Developer Studio with the "Open Qt Project File" option in the Qt Menu.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you're giving us, it seems you have the project generating your DLL set at the StartUp project. So whenever you click on run/debug, it will try to run the output of that project, in this case a DLL. Of course this won't work.

If there is a project for the example you want to run, right click on that project within the Solution Explorer and select "[Set as StartUp Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)". Now when you click on run/debug, it will run the output (the executable) of the project you selected.